# Simplest Method to Start AlarmManager With Time Value In Standard Format (ex 7:30)

Tags: java, android, time, alarmmanager

I'd like to start my AlarmManager activity at a time specified by the user however the time string is stored in standard format (ex - 7:30) how can I use the AlarmManager to interact with a long value which is stored in standard format - instead of miliseconds as it usually is? Is it possible to do this without converting it into miliseconds? If so - how? If not - what is the 2nd best alternative? (I simply need to know the easiest way to wake an alarm if my time string is in standard format.)

SOURCE:

```
 String time = 7:30 
 Intent intent2 = new Intent(New.this, Start.class);
        PendingIntent pintent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(Rules.this, 0, intent2,
                0);
        AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                time != null ? 1000 : 0, pintent2);
```

EDIT:

I'm attempting to use the following method I found:

```
public Date getTimeFromTimeString(String time)
    {
        String[] splitStrings = time.split(":");

        Date timeDate = new Date();
        timeDate.setHours(Integer.parseInt(splitStrings[0]));
        timeDate.setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(splitStrings[1]));
        return timeDate;
    }
```

However I'm getting warning stating:

```
The method setMinutes(int) from the type Date is deprecated
The method setSeconds(int) from the type Date is deprecated
```

Comment: Whats the problem with milliseconds?

Comment: My time format is in standard format - just wondering if there was a way to start an Alarm without converting it - I'm just looking for the simplest way to start the Alarm at the time specified by my "time" string.

Comment: If it is simpler to just convert it into miliseconds... I'd be happy to do so - I just need to know the simplest way to start this alarm if my time string is in standard format

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse your `String` into a `Calendar`. Pull the milliseconds from there.

Comment: I cant seem to find an example of how this can be done (specifically for HH:MM and converting into milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

There is a source code for Calendar in this link https://code.google.com/p/ancal/source/checkout
It contains calendar with appointments, tasks, and also alarm. I don't know that if it will help you or not. But if you examine the codes, you can find the things that you want to do.
(You must create SVN for downloading this project)